# Clear NGINX cache using FTP

Tags: caching, nginx

I have an NGINX server set-up to handle caching for a website (running elsewhere).

Works like  a charm, however we want to administrators to have an option to flush the cache from their backoffice. I was thinking of handling this using FTP, by simply removing all the files from the cache directory.

I have set up the caching like this:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/my_site levels=1:2 keys_zone=MY_SITE:8m max_size=2048m inactive=720m;
```

However the files are stored with permissions 700. How can I tell NGINX to also give permissions to the group (770)? I would add the FTP user I created to that group then.

Any other suggestion to handle the flushing would be OK (I heave read [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx)). The backoffice is located on another location so I would have to use some remote technology.

Comment: I think you get better help on Superuser or Serverfault

Answer (score 0):

You could use proxy_cache_purge directive, look for details http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_purge (this directive apeared in  1.5.7)