# How do you clear the cache for static files on nginx proxy server

Tags: caching, nginx

I have uploaded my new files on my server but it seems the cache has not refreshed as I can still see the same code.

It is the js files that I have changed.

I am using nginx and have also checked set the sendfile to 'Off' but still no joy.

Is there anyway i can clear the cache so i can see the updated files. The server is defintely holding the latest files.

Hope someone can assist.

Comment: Have you tried to include your script with attaching the latest version `?v12` on   `<script src="yourfile.js?v12" > </script>`?

Comment: there is no versioning on there. The server definitely has the correct copy on there as i did a quick vim on the file.

Comment: It is the way through which we can clear cache, in actual there is no any version of file, but it's dummy version(you can put any number).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can update your javascript file with adding the latest version with your file name, which is something like this.

```
<script src="yourfile.js?v12" > </script>
```

Here is the `?v12` the version of file  you can add.

Every time you edit the javascript file, you can update it like `?v13`, `?v14`, `?v15` so on.

- `<script src="yourfile.js?v13" > </script>`
- `<script src="yourfile.js?v14" > </script>`
- `<script src="yourfile.js?v13" > </script>`

That's how your javascript is not cached in browser.

Comment: There must be an alternative to this rather than doing versioning?

Comment: @tjhack Yes, use js merging. Some applications support this  and will generate a unique filename based on the content of the merge result. Overkill for this specific issue but it may benefit your site in more areas is to use Google's pagespeed module.