# Remove 301 Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I made the mistake of adding a `301` Redirect to my `.htaccess` file when I didn't want the redirect to be permanent.  So, my question is, how can I remove the redirect now?  Simply removing the code from the `.htaccess` file didn't work.  I've tried going to the URL on multiple browsers after refreshing the cache multiple times and it still redirects.

I have also tried replacing the `301` redirect with a different URL to see if it would atleast update the page, but that didn't work.

This is the code that was on the `.htaccess` file before:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^redirectURL.*$ http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This is what I've tried to change it to:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^differentRedirect/? http://www.othersite.com/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

Is something wrong with the syntax or is the real problem that I used a permanent redirect?

After doing a `curl -I` on the site I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 06 May 2014 03:13:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 343
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Location: http://www.website.com
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Wed, 07 May 2014 03:13:12 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Does that mean after Wednesday, 7 May it will no longer redirect???

Comment: Remember to clear your browser cache. Sounds like its your browser still having the same .htaccess and not reading the new one.

Comment: I'm doing a hard refresh, and I've tried multiple different browsers, and have tried going incognito on all three.  I know it's not the browser cache.  Is the server doing some caching???? It uses NginX I think.

Comment: @JakeGould See updated question with curl -I

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13116771/1370722) could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... funny story....

Apparently my web host just barely decided to migrate all of my content to a new server.  I didn't realize this and so I was editing the `.htaccess` file from the old server.  Once I changed the `.htaccess` file on the new server, everything worked great.

So, one thing that can be learned from this is, even if you do have NGINX, the `.htaccess` file is still vital and can still be used for server configuration.

I also decided to use the easier syntax below for my now TEMPORARY redirect:

```
Redirect 302 /page http://www.example.com/
```