# Django not reflecting changes to urls.py

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am setting up a login system for a Django site, which is running on an Nginx server.  I'm getting the following debug 404 page:

```
Using the URLconf defined in it.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^login/ [name='main_login']
^$ [name='index']
^laptops/
^assets/
^mardes/
^users/
^jobs/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, account/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

This appears to be using an old version of the it.urls file; the current one looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/',   include(admin.site.urls)                                          ),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account'), name='account'      ),
    url(r'^laptops/', include('laptops.urls', namespace='laptops')                      ),
    url(r'^assets/',  include('assets.urls',  namespace='assets')                       ),
    url(r'^mardes/',  include('mardes.urls',  namespace='mardes')                       ),
    url(r'^users/',   include('users.urls',   namespace='users')                        ),
    url(r'^jobs/',    include('jobs.urls',    namespace='jobs')                         ),
    url(r'^',        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='it/index.html'), name='index'  ),
) + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Which, as you can see, has no r'^login/' pattern.

I have set LOGIN_URL to '/account/login/' in my settings.py file, however the @login_required decorator is loading '/login/'.  The new url is also ignored when I specify login_url='/account/login' in the @login_required call.

I have restarted Nginx (both by starting and stopping, and running 'restart'), this has made no different.  I have also set 'sendfile=off' in the nginx.conf file.  I am guessing there is cache stored somewhere (re: [How to clear the cache of nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx)).

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: have you tried deleting all `pyc` files?  `find . -name \*.pyc -type f -delete`

Comment: @michaelb yes, I did try that, no change unfortunately

Comment: how are you running the django server? via uwsgi...?

Comment: @michaelb Yes, had forgotten about this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't run Django alone, but it should interact with a wsgi app server like [uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html) or [gunicorn](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html).

Maybe you should restart the wsgi app server instead of nginx.

Answer (score 0):

good catch @bcvery1. Also for those who are running django apps via passenger, restarting nginx or re-creating restart.txt file should also work to see those changes.