# Run command to docker container in a script

Tags: docker

I need run command to docker container in a script, i trying with:

```
docker run -it <container> /bin/bash -c "command"
```

I had no error but the command is not executed

Comment: Could you be more specific? e.g. `docker run -it <container> /bin/bash -c "echo 'Hello'"` works fine. <container> is centos in my case

Comment: I need clear cache on nginx container, i run: docker run -it nginx /bin/bash -c "rm -f /tmp/cache/*/*/*". If i launch this command inside container it work, in this way the cache is not cleared

Comment: that's because you should [commit you change](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/)

Comment: no, `docker commit nginx` successful, but the files are still there

Comment: I can not create a new image, i must not stop the service ... I do it manually

Comment: Did you try to run `docker exec <container_id> rm -f /tmp/cache/*/*/*`?

Answer (score 3):

> I can not create a new image, i must not stop the service ... I do it manually

It's possible to [invoke a command in a running container](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec):

```
docker exec <container_id> rm -f /tmp/cache/*/*/*
```

Comment: I have alredy trying, i not get any error but the files were not deleted

Comment: @user2385354 Are you sure that `rm -f /tmp/cache/*/*/*` is what you actually need? Are you going to remove `/tmp/cache` and all its subfolders? If so, then `rm -rf /tmp/cache` is what you need

Comment: If i launch `rm -rf` it erase all folder and nginx stop working, i need stop and start container, instead `rm -f` erase only file in all folder and suibfolder.

Comment: You may remove **all files** as follows `find /tmp/cache/ -type f -delete`. You may also add `-maxdepth <n>` if you want.

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6896903/2286990 suggests exactly this. See http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/best-way-to-empty-nginx-cache-tp3017271p3017429.html

Comment: I suspect for the answer to work you'd need to do:

`docker exec <container_id> rm -f "/tmp/cache/*/*/*"`