# Laravel Site Changes not showing

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I'm reposting my question because i've been stuck for a few days now. I'm using LEMP, , Laravel 4.2 :

[Previous post on StackE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622009/nginx-server-not-showing-changes-delete-cache/31622097?noredirect=1#comment51268304_31622097)

I make changes to my site, whether it's css or simple html and my changes are not being displayed by the browser. Nginx is not caching it and i've cleared my browser / Laravel cache. If you read the above link I added you'll see that I've tried all that.

When I navigate to the files after pulling the code from bitbucket the changes are there, it's just not rendering. Any new ideas? All help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into storage/framework/views ? Remove everything from this folder and try it.

Comment: @ArthurSamarcos no such folder. Only Laravel/app/storage/views and that folder only has .gitignore with nothing in it..

Comment: Ok I have an interesting update. My changes pull down successfully on my main site, just not the test site. So it appears to be a problem with the way i've set it up or linked it...