# nginx or lessc outputing unknown characters

Tags: css, nginx, less

I've got some less which I compile into css via the `lessc` command. If I open the output file in sublime, it looks fine:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
...
```

When I open the file in chrome (either directly by navigating to it or inspecting it via the devtools), however,

```
.heasder { test.}����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
...
```

this goes on for ~100 lines, then the css picks up as normal. The `.heasder{ test...` bit was from when I was testing. It's no longer in any files, let alone the file which the less is compiled into. My less file is literally only `@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";` for now while I'm trying to figure this out.

I've tried re-installing the less compiler, both via `npm` and via `apt-get`, no dice. I should also mention that I have disabled the cache while the devtools are open in chrome.

Comment: How do you compile? (Usually the problems with encoding are a result of mis-used `lessc src > dst` command line instead of the proper `lessc src dst`).

Comment: @seven-phases-max lessc src dest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with nginx's `sendfile` configuration. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx) for a good explanation.