# How does the Nginx+Flask interpret python source file?

Tags: python, nginx, caching, flask

I'm trying update a web project which based on the nginx+Flask+uwsgi. And when I updated any python files, I found nginx was still using the old ones. When I removed all *.pyc files, no new pyc file was generated by python interpreter. It looks like there is a cache, I followed the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx) to try to clear the cache of nginx. But it didn't work.

Does anybody know any solution to let nginx to interpret python from new source file?

This is the nginx.conf

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            off;
    #tcp_nopush          on;
    #tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    #types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name m.xxxx.com.cn;
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/root/003_exampleproject/exampleproject.sock;
        }
    }
```

And this is another config files:

```
(venv) [root@VM_0_3_centos 003_exampleproject]# cat /etc/systemd/system/exampleproject.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve exampleproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/root/003_exampleproject/
Environment="PATH=/root/003_exampleproject/venv"
ExecStart=/root/003_exampleproject/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini exampleproject.ini --logto /var/log/uwsgi/exampleproject.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

(venv) [root@VM_0_3_centos 003_exampleproject]# cat exampleproject.ini
[uwsgi]
module = manage:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = exampleproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
env = MBUS_ADMIN=root@example.com
```

Comment: I think is not problem of nginx - but of flask/uwsgi. Try to restart flask/uwsgi server - then nginx should serve new files.

Comment: I'm new for Flask. How should I restart flask/uwsgi except using systemctl to restart nginx?

Comment: It depends on the way how you are running your stack. There are few possibilities. In general uwsgi server is a layer below nging. Please provide more information what way you are running your app than I try to help.

Comment: I pasted the config files in the question. Is that enough?

Comment: I answered below - please let me know if this solution works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
service exampleproject restart
```

or

```
systemctl restart exampleproject.service
```

#### Long answer:

Regarding to your config files service that need to be restarted is:

```
exampleproject.service
```

If you run command

```
service --status-all
```

You should have it listed there.

Then you may use commands:

```
service exampleproject
```

will print allowed commands.

Try then:

```
service exampleproject restart
```

Note: service command should work on your centos, but if not work in your distribution you may try to use alternative:

```
systemctl restart exampleproject.service
```

Comment: It works. Thank you.
I kep trying `systemctl restart nginx`. T_T